# SonarRunner crashes due to Findbugs

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube, findbugs, sonar-runner

I am doing a Sonar analysis of my project on a Jenkins Server using SonarRunner within an ant build. Unfortunately, the Analysis crashes with the following lines:

```
[sonar:sonar] 11:29:57.008 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
[sonar:sonar] 11:29:58.217 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@5c1f0a26[id=3998,key=<key>,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-<key-batch>
[sonar:sonar] 11:29:58.247 DEBUG - To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] has been forcibly deregistered

BUILD FAILED
<Path>: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<Path>: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
```

I have other projects running on the same server, which have no problem performing this analysis (and where the analysis is triggered exactly the same way). As you can see, I changed the log level to DEBUG, but, nevertheless, I get no stack trace and I am not able to find useful information in the logs of Jenkins or Sonar. 
One other thing, I tried, was to increase the Heap space (with -Xmx) for this ant task in Jenkins but that didn't help either.

Are there any other settings I can take to get useful information or does somebody know about this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more information could be useful. E.g.: what SonarQube and SonarRunner versions are you running.

Findbugs is one of the few analyzing plugins that need .class data for analyzing the project. So if you have not changed the directory within your build.xml the ant task may search within the default output folder location.

Please make sure your .class files are located here. To make them appear here you have to compile them before of course

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction, I had to set the sonar.binaries property. Still don't know why it crashes without error message but no it is working :)

Comment: So as i guessed your .class data were not within the default location (I thing it was "bin/" folder) but within an other folder like "target". I am glad I could help you. :)